# "ev" element in an html file, what is it and how to parse?

Tags: javascript, python, html, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to locate and scrape the number of "comments" for a given review in this page: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2767052-the-hunger-games

Looks like a regular response call wont' work in this case. I have tried: `response.xpath("div1/div[3]/div1/a[2]/text()").re(r'.*(\d)\s.*')`

`response.xpath("div1/div[3]/div1/a[2]/text()").re(r'(\d)\s.*')`

`response.xpath("div1/div[3]/div1/a[2]/text()").response`

Nothing is returned

The page source (elements) shows that there is an "ev" element. Anyone could offer some clue how to approach this problem? Picture attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `ev` means `event` in the web inspector.

Comment: That's just [an indication by the Firefox Inspector that the element has an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners). If you had tried clicking on it, that should have been obvious.

Answer (score 3):

That's not an element. The debugger tool allows you to know that is the element (a tag in your example) which have JavaScript events.

Whenever you use any event on any element then the debugger tool place `ev` there so that you can know that there is some event attached.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am curious whether you could offer some suggestion on how to obtain the text of the a tag there? (should be the number of comments.